# Modal Dialog IlvFileBrowser

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

I am using Save As dialog of IlvFileBrowser as below

```
IlvFileBrowser dialog(SIDGetDisplay(),
    SIDGetSystemView(),
    NULL,
    1,
    extensions,
    descriptions);
dialog.setType(IlvFileSelectorSave);
dialog.setDirectory(lpStrDir);
dialog.setFileName(doc->getFilename());
dialog.setIndex(0);
dialog.moveToScreen();
```

If any other screen/ dialog from rogue-wave is open, the save-as dialog becomes non modal. Very strange. Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual void `IlvFileBrowser::show()` function to display dialog which is described as modal in the [documentation](http://docs.roguewave.com/visualization/views/5.5.1/refcppgadgets/classIlvFileBrowser.html#ac41a10c1326c968e5652219e192cae78). I can't see how `IlvFileBrowser::moveToScreen()` makes your `IlvFileBrowser` to display as modal dialog.

Comment: I was using get(). But unfortunately show() does not make the dialog modal either

Comment: The documentation says otherwise: "Displays the file browser as a modal dialog.

As a result of this the member functions getFileName, getPathName, and getDirectory are able to return the correct value."

Comment: Yes but when I user show() or get(), I can go back to the calling screen and launch another IlvFileBrowser dialog.